# How to change colors of avit theme in zsh

Tags: windows, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, zshrc

Hello I have recently installed zsh on my wsl windows 10. I have selected "avit" theme in .zshrc file and when I run "ls -ltr" I see these weird font colors that it is very hard to read the text.

How can I change the colors in zsh? Below is the snippet of the colors that I see. I am trying to change the yellow highlight in particular and have a different color to the letters.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try switching the theme, for example:

```
prompt walters
```

[Oh-My-ZSH](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes) & [Powerlevel 9K](https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k) would also support themeing.

Comment: Hello Martin, I did change the theme to agnosters and it does the same thing. Thanks for putting the inline image in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to figure this out. I was using WSL on windows and was running commands from Windows Terminal and in the terminal settings the "colorScheme" was set to "Campbell" and that's the reason for the weird colors.

I just had to change the "colorScheme" to something else on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/color-schemes